# How to extract text input value and pass down that value down to a child component as a prop to use for fetching third part api data in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to make a text input form displayed so the user can enter in what food items they have in their pantry.  I then want to take this data when the form is submitted and pass it down to a child component where I'd like to add that data into my query string as a variable in an axios.get() request.  I have tried changing the state of the input on submit in the parent component and pass that down as a prop to my child component (where all my api logic will be taking place).  The problem is that every time I type in the text input I am receiving the prop in the child component instead of only on submit.  This would then make the query string incorrect in the child component when I attempt to use the users input data in the get request.  Essentially I need a way to pass down the value of the text input only on Submit and then clear the state so that every new time a user inputs data, that will be a new api call.  Thanks in advance.  Here are my two components

PARENT COMPONENT: Input.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import ManipulateData from './ManipulateData'

function Input() {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('')
    const [saveState, setSaveState] = useState('')

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setInput(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setSaveState(input)
        setInput('');
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="pantryInput">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="pantryForm">
                    <label>Enter the ingredients you have for dinner</label>
                    <input value={input} onChange={handleChange} type='text' placeholder="What's in your pantry?" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <ManipulateData saveState={saveState} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Input
```

CHILD COMPONENT: ManipulateData.js

```
import React from 'react'

function DisplayData(props) {
    const string = props.saveState

    // .trim().replace(/,/gi, '').split(' ').join(',+')

    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(string)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default DisplayData
```

Comment: Check how `useEffect` works :)

Comment: No need for useEffect here. Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi judging by what you have above React is working as expected when I tested your code in CodePen.

I have updated your second component and it should now work, try it out and let me know.

Basically, you use a useEffect hook which will run every time the value in the dependency array changes (in your case the property). When it detects a change it will execute and we make a new API call with the update value.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

const ManipulateData = (props) => {
  const [apiResult, setApiResult] = useState();;

  useEffect(() => {
    handleApiRequest(props.saveState);
  }, [props.saveState])

  const handleApiRequest = async (value) => {
    try {
      //Make API Call and get result back
      // Set result to state using the setApiResult function
      const response = await axios.get(value);

      if (response) {
        setApiResult(response)
      }
      else {
        throw (error)
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      //Handle error
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{apiResult}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ManipulateData;
```

Comment: Glad I could help :) - If this resolved the issue can you please accept the answer so others can use this too.

Comment: Yes I just accepted it.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Only render your child component if saveState has value

```js
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="pantryInput">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="pantryForm">
                    <label>Enter the ingredients you have for dinner</label>
                    <input value={input} onChange={handleChange} type='text' placeholder="What's in your pantry?" />
                </form>
            </div>
            {saveState && <ManipulateData saveState={saveState} />} 
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: This works great for the first submission, however the same problem is happening once the saveState hook has a value.  After there is an initial value saved in saveState, I get the same issue every time the input is adjusted.  The prop is console.logged and will continuously  call  the api endpoint if I proceed with that functionality.  Thank you again for your answer.  Do you have any others ideas as to how to fix this?